# How do I keep the width of a table constant when it has dynamic content?

Tags: html

How do I keep the width of a table constant, even when the content of that table is interactively changing?

Old Post:

How do I insert a variable length tab in HTML? I want certain dynamic fields in my table to line up but they're changing width constantly.

EDIT: What I mean is this: in any text editor I can press tab to align certain bits of text, and not care about how many spaces there are. In fact, the number of spaces there needs to be for the leftmost part of the text can change, and I still won't care, as long as the text lines up. How do I do this is in HTML?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by variable length tab? You just want to add spaces? &nbsp; will do that, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: use colspan to make cells span mulitple columns?

Comment: Show your mark-up, then show us what you've *got* and explain, or ideally *show*, what you *want*. Live demos, at sites such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), are extraordinarily useful for this sort of thing (but *please* post your relevant/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) code *here*).

Comment: By default, a table column will be as wide as its widest cell. What do you mean by tab exactly?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a table layout with your alignment set to keep all the text in a specific column a the same place.  You aren't really going to be able to easily replicate the functionality of your Tab key in a text editor another way.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like what I'm looking for zshooter.

Comment: do u want to indent your code? Not clear at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best bet is just to apply a class like this:

```
.leftAlignedTable
{
    width: 90%; /*or whatever you want*/
}
```

This will ensure that your table is always the same width.

Answer (score 0):

Tables always line up. Even if you change the content, the table would grow and shrink to accommodate, and leave the alignment intact. That's kind of the point of a `<table>`.

If you set the `<table>`'s width with CSS to be a constant (or even a percentage) number, it won't change regardless of what content it has.

Comment: i have no clue what this guy is asking, but this sure aint it

Comment: @SajjanSarkar: That's my understanding of the question. He has a table that's constantly changing, and he wants to make sure the text always lines up. If that's not it, he'll just have to clarify it himself.

Comment: When I say it's constantly changing, I mean its interactively changing, in real time - what I'm asking is, how do I keep the width of a table constant over time?

Comment: just say <table width="90%"> or ur width in pixels ? or set it in CSS, does this not work?